# Samba+LDAP - Diagnosing Problems (Access Denied)

Tags: samba, smb, ldap, openldap, smbclient

I really need some help because I can't identify what's going on... I'm pretty lost here... =|

**PROBLEM:**

I have a server "server_a" with a directory "group_a_folder" ("/srv/group_a_folder") shared via Samba service available to everyone in LDAP service who is in the group "group_a".

There is a LDAP user "user_a" which in turn is in "group_a".

User "user_a" can access via ssh "server_a" (eg: `ssh user_a@10.0.0.10`).

User "user_a" can access "group_a_folder" share...

```
eg.: smb://DOMAIN_A%5Cserver_a@10.0.0.10/group_a_folder/
```

... if we give a permission...

```
chmod -R 777 /srv/group_a_folder
```

... to the folder "/srv/group_a_folder".

But if we change the permissions...

```
chmod -R 770 /srv/group_a_folder
```

... for the folder "/srv/group_a_folder" user "user_a" can no longer access the share.

---

**NOTES:**

I - I am currently migrating an environment with LDAP+Samba to a new server ("server_a"). On this server the user "user_a" can access the share "group_a_folder" (with "770" permissions);

II - In our tests users without access to group "group_a" do not access the share "group_a_folder" even though they have permission "777" as expected;

III - From what we can understand so far the problem is making Linux/Unix/CentOS 7 "understand" that group "group_a" should have access to share "group_a_folder" since when permission is "777" this happens perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

These are the symptoms of incorrect UUID/GUID mapping.
To verify this, please try the following:

*ls -n /srv/group_a_folder* -  which will you give the current GUID of the assigned group

*id user_a* - which will give you the GUID of his "group_a"

If they don't just change the GUID in /etc/groups of "group_a" to match the provided by LDAP.

*groupmod -g $ldap_GUID "group_a"*

Additional information can be found at:

Section "Identity mapping considerations" of https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html

Answer (score 0):

> From what we can understand so far the problem is making
>   Linux/Unix/CentOS 7 "understand" that group "group_a" should have
>   access to share "group_a_folder" since when permission is "777" this
>   happens perfectly.

First we put the server "server_a" in LDAP (domain controller). Eg...

```
authconfig\
 --enableldap\
 --enableldapauth\
 --ldapserver="ldap://some_ldap_server:389"\
 --ldapbasedn="dc=some_dc,dc=some_dc,dc=some_dc"\
 --enablemkhomedir\
 --enablelocauthorize\
 --updateall
```

Then give access to "group_a" in the folder "/srv/group_a_folder"...

```
chmod -R 770 "/srv/group_a_folder"
chown -R :"group_a" "/srv/group_a_folder"
```

Done! =D